# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-2

Here is what i'm doing and i'm getting this error

`echo empty($record['name']) ? $previous_data['w_name'] : $record['name'];`

what might be the problem? Reason why i'm trying to do is, i'm using this logic to update user's profile, if he doesn't want to update he can leave that field blank, and i've this previous_data array with his old information stored, if user leaves the field blank i'm going to store that previous value in it from previous data array but if user does change/update the field i'll store new value in it.

`$new_data = array(
     'name' => empty($record['name']) ? $previous_data['w_name'] : $record['name']
);`

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is: either `$record` or `$previous_data` is an object and you are accessing it as an array. you will need to access the member properly (i.e., `$record->name` instead of `$record['name']`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of accessing the properties by using $record['name'] try using $record->name.

As the error says, you are trying to treat an object as an array.